# Omniauth-Google error 401 - deleted_client

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oauth-2.0, omniauth, google-oauth

I am receiving a 401 - deleted_client from Google log in for my rails app. I had it working before but I unknowingly committed the id and secret to GitHub in my secrets.yml file.

I deleted the old and compromised client, made a new client id and changed the id and the secret in my omniauth.rb file and now every time I go to log in with Google it throws the 401 error. Do I need to refresh anything? I don't want to have to start the app over again.

```
Authorization Error
Error 401: deleted_client
The OAuth client was deleted.
```

Comment: What version of Rails are we talking about? If you are using Rails 5.2+ you should be using encrypted credentials. Its also hard to know what you're actually doing here. Did you just "solve" the problem by hardcoding the new credentials it into omniauth.rb? Or are you still using secrets.yml (which is as you have painstakingly learned is a bad idea)?

Comment: I am using Rails 6.0.2.2. I committed the secrets.yml, without realizing it. I deleted the app/client details on Google developer console, created new credentials and stored the new id and secret key in my .env file. I never hardcoded the credentials. I ran the .env variables through the omniauth.rb builder. Now my issue is when I use my app to try Google login, it throws the 401 error. I am new to Oauth. I apologize if this is obvious but I have not been able to find and understand a fix.

Answer (score 0):

In Rails 6 you want to use the encrypted credentials. Run `rails credentials:edit`. This will open a blank Yaml file in whatever editor you have configured for your shell such as vi, nano or emacs.

Add your credentials to the file:

```
google:
  client_id: "YOUR CLIENT ID"
  client_secret: "YOUR CLIENT ID"
```

When you save the file Rails will create `config/credentials.yml.enc` which is encrypted with `/config/master.key`. This key file should be in your gitignore while `config/credentials.yml.enc` can actually be commited in your repository.

In your `config/intializers/omniauth.rb` use the encrypted credentials:

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :google_oauth2, 
     Rails.application.credentials.google.fetch(:client_id),
     Rails.application.credentials.google.fetch(:client_secret)
end
```

### Why?

While ENV vars are less problematic then the old plaintext not-so-secret `secrets.yml` they do have a very big problem on their own. Any poorly written gem on the system can potentially output the entire ENV hash which will give an attacker all your credentials such as your database password.

With encrypted credentials the attacker not only needs the master key but also file system access at which point its really game over anyways.